# Pandas replace columns by merging another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1` looks like this:

```
     id  A   B
0    1   10  5
1    1   11  6
2    2   10  7
3    2   11  8
```

And another dataframe `df2`:

```
     id  A
0    1   3
1    2   4
```

Now I want to replace `A` column in `df1` with the value of `A` in `df2` based on `id`, so the result should look like this:

```
     id  A   B
0    1   3   5
1    1   3   6
2    2   4   7
3    2   4   8
```

There's a way that I can drop column `A` in `df1` first and merge `df2` to `df1` on `id` like `df1 = df1.drop(['A'], axis=1).merge(df2, how='left', on='id')`, but if there're like 10 columns in `df2`, it will be pretty hard. Is there a more elegant way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is one way to do it, by making use of pd.update. However, it requires to set the index on the id, so it can match the two df

```
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df.update(df2)
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(int)  # value by default was of type float
df.reset_index()
```

```
    id  A   B
0   1   3   5
1   1   3   6
2   2   4   7
3   2   4   8
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge just the `id` column from `df` to `df2`, and then `combine_first` it to the original DataFrame:

```
df = df[['id']].merge(df2).combine_first(df)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  id
0  3  5   1
1  3  6   1
2  4  7   2
3  4  8   2
```